# show app widget selection list

Tags: android

How to open app widget installation list that usually opens by users ?

long click on home screen and open wdget , I want to show this list .

I know this codes run when I user opens widget selection :

```
Starting activity: Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_PICK cmp=com.android.settings/.AppWidgetPickActivity (has extras) }

Displayed activity com.android.settings/.AppWidgetPickActivity: 470 ms (total 470 ms)
```

I assume which extras used for list ?
thanks

Comment: If you find a way to send this intent APPWIDGET_PICK, maybe it's possible. But from Honeycomb and later it seems this intent is no longer used

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Commonsware's answer to this question: [Add widget to homescreen from Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449884/add-widget-to-homescreen-from-application-android)

You can open the list, but you won't be able to use the selection, i.e., install the appwidget. In order to do that your application must have an AppWidgetHost working (home screen apps fall into this category)

Comment: I think this answer is correct, because of my researches and trials. But couldn't be ensured. Can anyone proof it by references?

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili well, I think Mark Murphy (CommonsWare) is an authority on Android development :) Should be a relevant reference. Just look at his reputation